# How to add an selected date from a datepicker to an model, in a declarative way

Tags: data-binding, model, datepicker, sapui5

is there a way from a Datepicker:

```
<DatePicker displayFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

chosen Date, to be automatically added to a model, in a declarative way?

Answer (score 0):

[Samples: DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.DatePicker/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker)

```
    <Panel
        id="dataBindingDatePanel"
        headerText="DatePicker using data binding">
        <Label text="DatePicker using DataBinding" labelFor="DP4"/>
        <DatePicker
            id="DP4"
            value="{path:'/dateValue', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true}}"
            class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
        <Text text="{path:'/dateValue', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'long'}}" class="sapUiSmallMargin"/>
    </Panel>
```